# C Troubles with comparison between two binary data

Tags: c

I am writing a program that get a path for a folder with two pictures files and a path for a file that containing binary data that simulator virus. and the purpose of this final project is to scan the files in the folder and say if one hold the virus. I succeeded with opening all the files but my comparison does not working. please someone help me fix this code because I am clueless why this is happening and this is my final project to get a grade on. The problem is in the line when I use `memcmp` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dirent.h"
#include <string.h>

int print_menu(char *argv[]); // this is a function that print to the user the menu and it's not appears in this question.
void long_scan(char *info[]);

#define STR_LEN 100

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int option = 0;
    if (argc == 3)
    {
        option = print_menu(argv);
        if (option == 0)
        {
            long_scan(argv);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The program didn't got the number of paramter's that she expect to get\n");
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
void long_scan(char *info[])
{

    DIR *file = 0; // the folder
    FILE *file_to_check = 0; // the files to check in this case the pictures
    FILE *virus; // the virus file
    struct dirent *files = 0;
    char temp[STR_LEN] = { 0 }; // using to play with the strings to open the files
    int len = 0, result = 0, c = 0, virus_len = 0, i = 0;

    char file_p[STR_LEN] = { 0 }; 
    char virus_path[STR_LEN] = { 0 };

    strcpy(file_p, info[1]); // the path of the folder
    strcpy(virus_path, info[2]); // the path to the virus

    file = opendir(file_p); // opening the folder

    strcat(file_p, "\\\\"); add "\\" to the path so I can get the files in the folder later on
    virus = fopen(virus_path, "rb"); // opening the virus

    fseek(virus, 0, SEEK_END);
    virus_len = ftell(virus); // get the virus len = 494
    fseek(virus, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char* virus_holder = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * virus_len); // create variable for the virus
    fread(virus_holder, sizeof(char), virus_len, virus); // get the virus to the variable (his len is 61 dont know why)

    if (file == NULL) // check if the file exist
    {
        printf("Error. file does not exists\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    while ((files = readdir(file)) != NULL) // get one file every time
    {
        if (strcmp(files->d_name, "..") && strcmp(files->d_name, "."))
        {
            strcpy(temp, file_p); // copy the original path for later
            strcat(file_p, files->d_name); // get the path to the file
            file_to_check = fopen(file_p, "rb"); // open the file (picture)
            fseek(file_to_check, 0, SEEK_END);
            len = ftell(file_to_check); // get the file len
            fseek(file_to_check, 0, SEEK_SET);
            char* buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * len); // create buffer to hold the file binary data
            fread(buffer, sizeof(char), len, file_to_check);
            fclose(file_to_check);
            /*******/
            result = memcmp(virus_holder, buffer, virus_len); // here the problem his. for some resone th compare does not work for me. and one of the file his holding the virus for 100%
            /*******/
            if (result == 0)
            {
                printf("%s is holding the virus\n", files->d_name);
            }
            strcpy(file_p, temp); // get the original path
            free(buffer);
        }
    }
    free(virus_holder);
}
```

Comment: As pasted in your post, this code does not compile even after adding includes for string.h and stdlib.h. I believe your `strcat` call should be followed by a comment token. But the fact remains you're running a version that we can't see. And `exit` takes an argument. And, by convention, you should not cast a `malloc` return value.

Comment: it's not compile because I did not put the print_menu function in my code just set the option variable to 0

Comment: The general rule is to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a specific problem.

Comment: The way your code is written right now you'll only find a virus if it is right at the beginning of the file. I would guess you're supposed to scan through the whole file searching. Iterate through and search for the first byte, then use `memcmp` there. If you find it then do whatever you're supposed to in that case, if not keep looking for that first byte until you reach the end of the file data.

Comment: And you're not checking the return values of `fread`, `fseek`, and `fopen`.

Comment: what do you mean by checking the return values from fread, fseek and fopen?\

Comment: If `fopen`, for example, fails to open a file, then its return value will be NULL and any attempt to access it later with, say, `fseek` will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: You should use `openfol` to open folders, and `opendir` to open directories.

Comment: and I do need to sacn all the file not only the beginning

Comment: (1) You need to debug this, to understand where is the first place in the code that "things went wrong". For example, check the value of "len" for the file that contains the virus. Does it make sense? (2) If the virus currently contains "weird" characters, e.g. characters that are not part of ASCII, it may cause problems. Try to check your program with a virus that contains only english letters and digits, and only later check a "virus" that contains other types of characters as well.

Comment: Is the virus is at the beginning of the file, or anywhere in the file? [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) seems like the thing to use; lots of Regular Expression libraries implement.

Comment: @Neil If you have a problem that you think can be solved using regular expressions, you end up with two problems

Comment: @4386427 Three really, because at least one of the files has a virus. :)

Comment: If the virus is constant, you could hard-code it in `re2c`. Although, if you're not worried about performance, a simple sliding window would do. Assuming that "hold the virus" means what I think.

Comment: @4386427 Neil said that some RE libraries use the algorithm, but not that the OP should use RE. Please read careful before moaning. ;-)

Comment: Anyway, @roeeattias, your problem is that the single call of `memcmp()` tries to find the virus signature only at the beginning of the file. Without looking at efficiency, you need to implement an algorithm to look at other places, too. Only if your solution is too slow, you need to find a more clever algorithm.

Comment: You might try something like this: https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-825.26/string/FreeBSD/memmem.c.auto.html